# Form Customizer won't load

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, custom, form-customization

It starts to load and then redirect to error message - Component ID is not defined:

```
Error details: Error: Error initializing application. Error: Error: Error preloading the page-based application. Error: Error: Component ID is not defined
```

It is newly generated Form Customizer

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "initialPage": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/workbench",
  "https": true,
  "api": {
    "port": 5432,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  },
  "serveConfigurations": {
    "default": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx",
      "formCustomizer": {
        
        "ContentTypeID": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118006CA2BEE5D9A8C142A32C154E21BEEE4500B8A07C62F24F0945961C3EE5495E2DD4",
        "componentId": "0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635",
        "PageType": 8,
        "RootFolder": "/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/"
      }
    },
    "someBot": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/TestPage.aspx",
      "customActions": {
        "fef12b54-30af-48e9-a4b3-2416e03b59a4": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer",
          "properties": {
            "testMessage": "Test message"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sitePages_NewForm": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx",
      "formCustomizer": {
        "componentId": "0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635",
        "PageType": 8,
        "RootFolder": "/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/"
      }
    },
    "sitePages_EditForm": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx",
      "formCustomizer": {
        "componentId": "0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635",
        "PageType": 6,
        "RootFolder": "/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/",
        "ID": 1
      }
    },
    "sitePages_ViewForm": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx",
      "formCustomizer": {
        "componentId": "0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635",
        "PageType": 4,
        "RootFolder": "/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/",
        "ID": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to open it with this link:
https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx?List=64351986-8c79-4c31-96f6-34bd94292709&componentId=0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635&PageType=8&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FmySubsite%2FSitePages%2F